# DHTMLX Scheduler Start_hour

Tags: scheduler, dhtmlx, dhtmlx-scheduler

I have two questions related to DHTMLX

QUESTION 1: how to start_hour with minutes.

[Start_hour_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39KfL.png)

QUESTION 2: how to start_hour with PM (Post Meridiem)

[Start_hour_with_pm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0P78.png)

Answer (score 0):

Minutes are not supported in first_hour config, in Day/Week/Unit views you can set only hour as a minimum value for the scale.
You can [block time](https://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/limits.html) from 05:00 to 05:30 to prevent events creation.
Start minutes on the scale can be configured only in Timeline view.

To start from 5pm, set

```
scheduler.config.first_hour = 17;
```

It doesn't mean that current date 17:00-24:00 and the next day till 10:00 (if you set, for example, "last_hour = 10") will be rendered on the scale. You need to set values for these configs within one day. I.e. 0:00 <= first_hour < last_hour <= 24:00.